# Simple error checking with mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using $mysqli->query all over the place without any sort of error checking or fall back if the query fails.

What's the simplest/cleanest method I can use to catch these ?

I'm thinking of a little function which can just display a friendly message and send me an email - I can write that but am not sure how to trigger/call it only when an error occurs? without adding heaps of if statements...

i.e I wrap them all like:

if($mysqli->query($query))
 blah
} else {
 error
}

That will really bloat my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own database class that extends mysqli, and does the error catching/emailing when you call `my_mysqli->doQuery()`:

```
class my_mysqli extends mysqli
{
  function doQuery($query)
  {
    if($this->query($query)) return $blah } else { do error blah }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. Thanks!

What other useful things would you do with that class?